# The calendar control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

Calendar Class

.NET Framework 2.0 Other Versions

Displays a single-month calendar that allows the user to select dates and move to the next or previous month.

Namespace: System.Web.UI.WebControls

Assembly: System.Web (in system.web.dll)

### Questions

> 1. By default which calender type does it use? (english,german,western,eastern etc  i guess, or the servers bios settings time/date?)
> 2. Is it fully dependent on the systems clock settings? (well no explanation here yes or no? if yes then answer point 3)
> 3. Any way to provide web synchronization? (so that dependency on server time and date is removed)

Comment: What do you mean by calendar type? Language? Cultural?

Comment: You might be better of splitting this into multiple questions. Be sure to use a descriptive title for each question.

Comment: @user: also, since you want to learn, the Calendar control and other controls are not part of C#. They are part of ASP.NET, which is part of .NET. The same controls can be used by all .NET languages (VB.NET, F#, etc), not just by C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.not 100% what you mean, you can return it to string or datetime
2. dependent on the server time
3.not sure what you mean, you can store a date in a database and use that to set what date your calendar starts